# I can't make this.getAttribute working, the browser says it's not a function

Tags: javascript

The browser says that this.getAttribute is not a function. I've seen a similar post on Stack, the OP was told to send this to the function, but it doesn't work for me. Here's the snippet:

```
function reveal()
{
    this.src = "img/" + this.getAttribute("data-value") + ".png";
}

function display_cards(cards, n)
{
    for (i = 0; i < cards.length; i++)
    {
        if (i % n == 0)
        {
            document.getElementById("container").innerHTML += '<br/>';
        }
        document.getElementById("container").innerHTML += '<img src="img/back.png" class="card" onclick="reveal(this)" data-value="'+cards[i]+'"/>';
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you expect `this` to refer to?  If it's not a DOM element, and you don't have your own function called `getAttribute()`, then it won't work. You really didn't post enough code for context.

Comment: You are not going to get the context of the image you clicked with an inline event listener. You set it up to use the argument `onclick="reveal(this)"` and you are not using it `function reveal()`

Answer (score 2):

Get `this` in function as an incoming parameter: `function reveal(img)`, for example.

```js
const cards = ["linear-flat-wedding-monograms_52683-64319",
            "flat-car-poster-with-photo-horizontal_52683-64510",
            "gradient-grainy-gradient-shapes_23-2148975080"];

display_cards(cards,3)



function reveal(img)
{
    img.src = "https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/" + img.getAttribute("data-value") + ".jpg";
}

function display_cards(cards, n)
{
    for (i = 0; i < cards.length; i++)
    {
        if (i % n == 0)
        {
            document.getElementById("container").innerHTML += '<br/>';
        }
        document.getElementById("container").innerHTML += '<img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/gradient-grainy-gradient-shape-set_23-2148971570.jpg" class="card" onclick="reveal(this)" data-value="'+cards[i]+'"/>';
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked!